# Problemas con OSRM con R y Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu

Tengo un error de memoria con R en ubuntu, y no se como solucionarlo. Levante un servidor ORMS con el mapa de Chile, y estoy haciendo mas o menos 64 millones de consultas sobre ruteo (distancia y duración, en auto). El error que me arroja es:

```
The OSRM server returned an error:
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb
```

Al pedir solo la distancia, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
 The OSRM server returned an error:
Error in grepl("\\\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]", str): could not allocate memory (2047 Mb) in C                           function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'
```

Tengo la impresión que es un problema de memoria de R, ya que el computador tiene 12 gb de RAM.

La sintaxis que estoy ocupando es la siguiente:

```
options(osrm.server = "http://xxxxxxxxx:5000/")
data <- read.csv("base_master.txt", sep="|", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data <- data[,c(1,8,7)]
ruta <- osrmTable(data,measure = c("distance","duration"))
```

Espero puedan ayudarme!

Gracias.

Comment: Claramente R está necesitando hasta 2 Gb libres para alocar y el SO no dispone de estos. ¿El servidor está corriendo en el mismo equipo?

Comment: Si, corre en el mismo equipo. He monitoreado el uso de memoria y no se cae por eso. El problema es como expandir los límites de memoria de R. Estoy trabajando en una maquina de AWS con las siguientes carqcterísticas de memoria:

Mem:    Total:15G      used: 2.0G      free:12G     shared:800K     buff/cache: 965M        available:13G

Comment: Prueba ejecutar en R: `system('grep MemFree /proc/meminfo')` justo antes del código que te da error, al menos sabrás cuanta memoria disponible tienes en ese momento.

Comment: Mejor ejecutar `system('grep MemAvailable /proc/meminfo')` ya que esto te da la memoria disponible (incluye memoria que esta usada por buffers etc, pero sigue siendo disponible).

Comment: Que te da el `memory.limit()` en `R`?

Comment: Monitoreo la memoria con el top, y no pasa el 40%. Al parecer es un problema de memoria del R. Memory.limit() es un comando de Windows,  no aplica en Ubuntu.

Comment: También siento decir que `memory.limit()` ni `system('...)` pueden ser usados directamente en **macOS** que está basado en `UNIX`... no `Linux`, el último está condicionado a la versión de `ggc` que viene integrada con el `Xcode` de `Apple`. Asimismo @MaximilianoRomero hay un post dónde se hacen recomendaciones sobre lo expuesto [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

Comment: He podido crear con éxito una matriz con **20 millones de NA** en la iMac (arquitectura de 64bits) `a <- matrix(NA, 200000000, 10)` que son **~7.5GB** (similar a bajar la data del servidor), pero, al querer hacer la siguiente operación `a[,c(1,8,7)]<-1` simplemente obtengo *`Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`* y no sé que tan factible sea en vuestro caso **"Lotizar"** el vector (`b<-a[1:100000,c(1,8,7)]` `b[,1:3]<-1 no aparece el error en mi caso), o aplicar una [matriz sparse](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/)

Comment: toda vez que necesitas al parecer la distancia y duración a partir de la matriz completa, mediante la función [osrmTable](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/osrm/versions/3.2.0/topics/osrmTable)

Comment: Podrías tomar el punto final e inicial como datos de entrada en google maps y calcular la distancia (con la duración es subjetivo porque depende del tipo de vehículo, si ha llevado carga y de qué tipo, para que sea un dato fiable ha considerar) y ver si partiendo el vector `data[,c(1,8,7)]` se obtienen resultados similares, porque creo que google emplea otro método a travez de su `Matrix API`. Aquí también dejo [GraphHopper Directions API (1.0.0)](https://docs.graphhopper.com/) que es otra Matriz API para calcular distancias y pueda visualizarse mejor las comparaciones.

Comment: Sólo tener en cuenta @MaximilianoRomero, que si se va ha trabajar por tramos, la fila final viene ha ser la fila inicial del siguiente `lote`, supongamos que `data` sólo tiene `30` filas y se quiere realizar la operación en tres (`3`) `batches` (lotes) `data[1:10,c(1,8,7)]; data[10:20,c(1,8,7)] y data[20:30,c(1,8,7)]` he ir sumando las distancias y duraciones obtenidas en cada tramo. Asimismo, el tamaño del **lote** estará condicionado a la arquitectura y especificaciones técnicas de vuestra máquina virtual.